# Leaflet, else if = show no marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, font-awesome

I need a way to show no marker or invisible marker at the below "if and else if".
I have a feature property value that is not allowed to be visible on the map
Any suggestion would be great as I am out of ideas

Thanks

```
pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var stt = feature.properties.sid;
    var prd = feature.properties.utl;
    var marker;

    // filter
    if (stt === 162341 && prd === 'A') {
        marker = new L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'th-large', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'darkblue'}) });
      } else if (stt === 162341 && prd === 'B') {
        marker = new L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'navicon', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'darkblue'}) });
      } else if (stt === 162341 && prd === 'AB') {
        marker = new L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'list', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'darkblue'}) });
      } else if (stt === 162341 && prd === 'X') {
        marker = new L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'circle-thin', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'darkblue'}) });
      } else {
        marker = show no marker on map with this property value};
      }
    return marker;
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Have you tried `marker = null;` ?

Comment: It's entirely clear what you're asking, but... maybe just remove the `else` branch?

Comment: Also, minor rewrite suggestion: https://pastebin.com/RHHgNfC2

Comment: Why on earth did I not thought of "null"... :)  Great rewriting, much cleaner than mine, it's taken cheers

Answer (score 1):

You're using `pointToLayer`, which tells me you're using `L.GeoJson` to parse some GeoJSON and create markers from that.

Let me quote the [Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#geojson-option) about possible options for a `L.GeoJson`:

> `pointToLayer` A `Function` defining how GeoJSON points spawn Leaflet layers. It is internally called when data is added, passing the GeoJSON point feature and its `LatLng`. The default is to spawn a default `Marker`
>
> `filter` A `Function` that will be used to decide whether to include a feature or not. The default is to include all features

With that in mind it should be obvious that one can use *both* a `filter` function (which should return `false` for those points to not be shown) and then a `pointToLayer` function (which should instantiate `Marker`s for the non-filtered-out points).